# Trying to get the twitter_auth api to work.. getting no such file to load (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
$ rails g twitter_auth
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require': no such file to load -- twitter_auth/engine (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
    ...
```

Anyone know what I might be missing? I thought this was straight forward.

```
#Gemfile
gem "twitter-auth", :require => "twitter_auth/engine"
```

then :

```
bundle install
```

Comment: How did you install this gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're probably trying to use one of the forks of twitter-auth (perhaps [trotter's fork](https://github.com/trotter/twitter-auth) or [jaikoo's fork](https://github.com/jaikoo/twitter-auth)?). Both look like they have slightly misleading readmes because they suggest you can install from rubygems. However, the gem 'twitter-auth' is the main branch of the plugin, by [mbleigh](https://github.com/mbleigh/twitter-auth) which doesn't work with Rails 3 yet by the looks of it.

If you're wanting to use one of these forks which work with Rails 3, you need to specify their git repo in your Gemfile. For example, for jaikoo's fork:

```
gem "twitter-auth", :git => "git://github.com/jaikoo/twitter-auth.git", :branch => "rails_3", :require => "twitter_auth/engine"
```

Then `rails g twitter_auth` should work as expected.

Comment: I got the generator to work.  But the helpers don't seem to work.    before_filter :login_required in my controller it returns | undefined local variable or method `login_required' for #<TimelineController:0xa8568f8>

Comment: Apologies, it looks like you do still need the `:require => "twitter_auth/engine"` part in the gemfile. I'll update my answer.